# file encoding changes when appending

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

I want to write a file using `write.table` and use `UTF-8` as `encoding`. This works as long as I don't append to this file. When I do, the `encoding` changes to `ANSI`. Why is that and how can I prevent this?

Here is a small example code:

```
options("encoding" = "UTF-8")
write.table("Hello World in UTF-8", file = "C:/TEMP/test.txt", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "", quote = FALSE)
write.table("Now it changes to ANSI", file = "C:/TEMP/test.txt", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "", quote = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

I also tried to use `fileEncoding = "UTF-8"` directly in `write.table`, but the result is the same.

Comment: How to do you know `encoding` has changed to `ANSI`? For me, it works just fine. The file is still in `UTF-8`.

Comment: I open the file in Notepad++ and it tells me the `encoding`.

Comment: I too used Notepad++ and it shows me `UTF-8` encoding.

Comment: OK. It seems it is a problem of NP++ rather than R. If I close the file and open it again, it tells me `UTF-8`, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I prefer not to rely on global `option`. Using `fileEncoding` parameter to `write.table` safeguards your code from any changes in global `option`. Hence the line should be:

```
write.table("Now it changes to ANSI", file = "C:/TEMP/test.txt", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "", quote = FALSE, append = TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```